# quick filter very small (of a selected cell)

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I work with filter in excel for a specific file… I wonder if it Is possible to increase permanently the zoom of the quick filter (working with the shorcut Alt+down) of a selected cell (without modifying the current zoom of my sheet). Indeed you can see on the picture below that the quick filter in my selected cell appears with very small words and it is not very legible…

If someone know the solution (with a macro or not), that would be really great.

Thanks in advance.
Xavi
[image]

Comment: You can use a Combobox as an overlay, that appears when the cell with data validation is selected. Look at the [Contextures](https://contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html) site for instructions.

Comment: Lowering overall font of the sheet and zooming in would be the easier way

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you! Finally I decided that I will process like that: first I select my cell, then Ctrl+mouse wheel (scroll up) to zoom bigger and Alt+down to get my filter inside my cell, afterward Ctrl+mouse wheel (scroll down) to zoom smaller (to come back to the normal state)...